# In Emmet what decides whether there will be a new line produced by the HTML codes?

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I'm using Sublime Text 2, with the Emmet plugin

This emmet code

```
form>label{blah}+input[type="button"]
```

produces this, one line of output, with no new lines

```
<form action=""><label for="">blah</label><input type="button"></form>
```

This emmet code

```
form>label{blah}+input[type="button"]
```

produces also a single line of output, no new lines

```
<form action=""><label for="">blah</label><input type="button"></form>
```

This emmet code

```
form>label{blah}+input[type="button"]+input[type="button"]
```

Produces new lines in the output

```
<form action="">
  <label for="">blah</label>
  <input type="button">
  <input type="button">
</form>
```

I cannot see what controls whether it produces new lines or not

It can't be the existence of a second element in general, because  `form>label{blah}+label{blah}`  produces one line.

So, what controls whether it produces new line or not?

Comment: It is controlled by output profile: http://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok I know it might be something in snippets.json but can you be more specific?

Comment: It’s not `snippets.json`, it’s `syntaxProfiles.json`. Please read docs

Answer (score 0):

When you use the code
 `form>label{blah}+input[type="button"]` 
    Emmet assumes you **do not** want a list of items so it can and does 
put a single item on the same line.
When you added the second item in your
code line `form>label{blah}+input[type="button"]+input[type="button"]`
    Emmet assumes you want a list of items. So Emmet places more than one of
the same item on different line so that coders, like you and I, have an easier time
distinguishing them from one another. The second code line has different 
edit points than the first code line. You can check this with the go to next
edit point command. This is so because you have two of the same item. These
items could be siblings as you have here or they could be `parent>child` they
will be on separate lines except the child will be indented.
Add a `p>` tag just after the `form>`
`form>p>label{blah}+input[type="button"]`
 This will output:-
`<form action="">`
`<p><label for="">blah</label><input type="button"></p>`
Label and input are on a newline together.
Or the following code example
`form>label{blah}+p>input[type="button"]`
 
This will output:-
`<form action="">`
`<label for="">blah</label>`
`<p><input type="button"></p>`
Both label and input will have their own line. Although label and input should normally be on the same line.
A form expects at least one label and one input. In Emmet, when you satisfy the expected, you get your code on a single line but when there is more than one of the same element it will list them on separate lines. You can control this behaviour-(Canadian spelling) with a p> tag as I have shown. You can modify change or add to the `snippets.json` file to get a particular behaviour or even new snippets and Emmet commands. I hope this helps.